# Mobile Buy SDK Android-how to include Add cart button with Quanity(Nos)

Tags: android, api, android-studio, e-commerce, shopify

I have downloaded the **Mobile Buy SDK Android** latest version from this https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android/releases/ link and I have successfully run the sample project by following this https://docs.shopify.com/mobile-buy-sdk/android/integration-guide steps.

**What I did**

When selecting the particular product from list of showing products it will forward to the

`ProductDetailsActivity` and there it has the option to `checkout` the product. so currently it is useful for buying a single product.

*ProductListActivity.java*

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (useProductDetailsActivity) {
                        launchProductDetailsActivity(products.get(position));
                    } else {
                        createCheckout(products.get(position));
                    }
                }
            });
```

*SampleApplication.java*

```
public void launchProductDetailsActivity(Activity activity, Product product, ProductDetailsTheme theme) {
    ProductDetailsBuilder builder = new ProductDetailsBuilder(this, buyClient);
    Intent intent = builder.setShopDomain(buyClient.getShopDomain())
            .setProduct(product)
            .setTheme(theme)
            .setShop(shop)
            .setWebReturnToUrl(getString(R.string.web_return_to_url))
            .setWebReturnToLabel(getString(R.string.web_return_to_label))
            .build();
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

the above code snippet has been used for buying a single product.

**What I need**

I have to add two options "**Quantity**"-`EditText` and "**Add Cart**"-`Button` in this `ProductDetailsActivity` from these options user can purchase a multiple items with as many nos as he need. so that he need to pay for one time for all products which he selected.

`launchProductDetailsActivity()method` in `SampleApplication.java` is calling some default method in **buy-1.2.0 library**. So how can I add `add Cart` option with `quantity` selection.